# Register a user through URL

Tags: users

How can I create a new user account through a URL?

Basically I have build a new simple site with Drupal 8. Direct registration is not possible, but it should be managed by a third party service. This service can only call URL in the format http://mysite/user/register?name=abc&password=def.

Comment: You should never make database changes based on a `GET` request, always use a `POST` with authentication. Drupal does things properly, and I doubt any contributed module which provided such functionality would get through the security review process, so you're probably looking at a custom implementation if you can't reconsider the approach

Comment: Drupal 8 allows to create an account via its REST API. You need Drupal 8.3, but I am not sure you can make the REST API use a URL like the one you described.